# How to script SSH connection using keypair and password?

Tags: ssh, mysql

I managed to login to my hosting provider manually with this command:

```
ssh -i /path/to/key-ssh me@mydomain.com
```

The server then asks for a password, and login succeeds.

Now I want to automate a MySQL backup, so I need to login using a shell script.
(to be clear: my provider requires a keypair and a password both to login)

Then I tried to use sshpass:

```
sshpass -p 'MYPASSWORD' ssh me@mydomain.com
```

Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Then I tried this:

```
sshpass -p 'MYPASSWORD' ssh -i /path/to/key-ssh me@mydomain.com
```

With this the remote server does not respond at all (prompt freezes)

My server runs Debian 8.10 (Jessie)

I am aware of the security risks using sshpass, but I am the only one using this server.
I also tried automysqlbackup, but it gives my a headache trying to get it to work over ssl.

Automating a backup over SSH seemed the simplest solution (of which I'm no so sure anymore...)

Comment: Are you sure the server asks you for a password? Or are you entering the _passphrase_ for your private key?

Comment: I think it is the passphrase (sorry I'm no expert...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server isn't asking for your password. What you are typing is the passphrase that protects your private key.

To log in automatically without having to type the passphrase, you first have to remove the passphrase. You do it via the command:

```
ssh-keygen -p
```

Be careful to keep your private key in a safe place, though, as without a passphrase anyone could use it.

Comment: To add onto this, you can also use `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` to load your key into memory. This way you can keep your passphrase and only need to enter it once.